# Does the order of building kernel or world first matter?

Tags: freebsd

Now I have to build world and kernel in my freeBSD, the freeBSD handbook
tells me that I have to build world first, but I don't know why ? Does the
order matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably OT here, but just follow the handbook.   You need to build world first to build the new C compiler and some other tools that are required to build the kernel. Depending upon how big of a jump you are going, it *might* not matter, but better to be safe than sorry, just follow the directions and `make buildworld` first.

from the handbook

```
Use the new compiler residing in /usr/obj to build the new kernel, 
in order to protect against compiler-kernel mismatches. 

This is necessary, as certain memory structures may have changed, 
and programs like ps and top will fail to work if the kernel and 
source code versions are not the same.
```